# Mapping One to Many where one parent having two links to a child

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many

How to configure EF mapping for the following relations:

```
public class OrderBook : BaseEntity
{
        public OrderBook()
        {
            BuyOrders = new List<OrderBookItem>();
            SellOrders = new List<OrderBookItem>();
        }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderBookItem> BuyOrders { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderBookItem> SellOrders { get; set; }
}

public class OrderBookItem : BaseEntity
{
        public OrderType Type { get; set; }
        public int OrderBookId { get; set; }

        public virtual OrderBook OrderBook { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried a few variations

```
public class OrderBookMap : DynamicLoadEntityTypeConfiguration<OrderBook>
    {
        public OrderBookMap()
        {
            ToTable(nameof(OrderBook));
            this.HasKey(p => p.Id);

            //this does not work
            //this.HasMany<OrderBookItem>(p=>p.BuyOrders).WithRequired(i=>i.OrderBook).HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.OrderBookId);
            //this.HasMany<OrderBookItem>(p=>p.SellOrders).WithRequired(i=>i.OrderBook).HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.OrderBookId);
        }
    }

    public class OrderBookItemMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderBookItem>
    {
        public OrderBookItemMap()
        {
            ToTable(nameof(OrderBookItem));
            this.HasKey(p => p.Id);

            //this leads to extra columns created 
            this.HasRequired(i => i.OrderBook).WithMany(d => d.BuyOrders).HasForeignKey(i => i.OrderBookId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            this.HasRequired(i => i.OrderBook).WithMany(d => d.SellOrders).HasForeignKey(i => i.OrderBookId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        }
    }
```

But the mapping result is incorrect, i think it is enough to have one FK between OrderBook and OrderBookItem tables:
[image]

the Type property might be used somehow as it helps to distinct which item is Buy or Sell.

Comment: Single relationship maps to one reference, one FK and one collection navigation property. If the idea is to have "logical" relationship based on `OrderType`, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I decided it would be better to split it on 3 tables rather than having OrderBook_id1 and OrderBook_id2:
OrderBook
BuyOrder
SellOrder

So the entities and mapping end up as the following:

```
 public class OrderBook : BaseEntity
    {
        public OrderBook()
        {
            BuyOrders = new List<BuyOrder>();
            SellOrders = new List<SellOrder>();
        }

        public virtual ICollection<BuyOrder> BuyOrders { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SellOrder> SellOrders { get; set; }

    }

    public abstract class OrderBookItem : BaseEntity
    {
        public int OrderBookId { get; set; }
        public virtual OrderBook OrderBook { get; set; }
    }

    public class BuyOrder : OrderBookItem
    {

    }

    public class SellOrder : OrderBookItem
    {

    }

    public class OrderBookMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderBook>
    {
        public OrderBookMap()
        {
            ToTable(nameof(OrderBook));
            this.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        }
    }

    public class BuyOrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<BuyOrder>
    {
        public BuyOrderMap()
        {
            Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable(nameof(BuyOrder));
            });
            this.HasKey(p => p.Id);
            this.HasRequired(i => i.OrderBook).WithMany(d => d.BuyOrders).HasForeignKey(i => i.OrderBookId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }

    public class SellOrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<SellOrder>
    {
        public SellOrderMap()
        {
            Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable(nameof(SellOrder));
            });
            this.HasKey(p => p.Id);
            this.HasRequired(i => i.OrderBook).WithMany(d => d.SellOrders).HasForeignKey(i => i.OrderBookId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
```